# Conflict resolution in ZODB

Tags: python, django, zodb

I do run parallel write requests on my **ZODB**. I do have multiple `BTree` instances inside my ZODB. Once the server accesses the same objects inside such a `BTree`, I get a `ConflictError` for the `IOBucket` class. For all my Django bases classes I do have `_p_resolveconflict` set up, but can't implement it for `IOBucket` 'cause its a C based class.

I did a deeper analysis, but still don't understand why it complains about the `IOBucket` class and what it writes into it. Additionally, what would be the right strategy to resolve it?

Thousand thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IOBucket` is part of the persistence structure of a `BTree`; it exists to try and reduce conflict errors, and it does try and resolve conflicts where possible.

That said, conflicts are not always avoidable, and you should restart your transaction. In Zope, for example, the whole request is re-run up to 5 times if a `ConflictError` is raised. Conflicts are ZODB's way of handling the (hopefully rare) occasion where two different requests tried to change the exact same data structure.

Restarting your transaction means calling `transaction.begin()` and applying the same changes again. The `.begin()` will fetch any changes made by the other process and your commit will be based on the fresh data.

Comment: Dear I use django_zodb, where the transaction is startet quite earlier and I would not intercept it. What I found yesterday is that calling root._p_jar.sync() before the change and transaction.savepoint after the change to the data store solved the conflict error. though I not fully understood the logic. does it make sense or did  I something weird?

Comment: another questions: so it would make sense to build a loog which catches the exception for about 5 times, then waits a few ms and then retries with a complete new transaction?

if it is so. I had in mind, that my transaction starts upon the servers request and ends when the response is rendered. this would be obsolete then? So for my very secure environment complex transactions will not be a good approach with zodb? these transactions should be more ACID like?

Comment: @patroqueeet: `_p_jar.sync()` means load latest data (which means you now could be working with an inconsistent state). The `savepoint` is just a means of flushing changes to disk (so free up memory) until commit time.

Comment: @patroqueeet: I am not familiar with `django_zodb`; a quick glance at the middleware component of that package indeed shows that it doesn't retry the request. Compare that to the [`pyramid_tm`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tm/en/latest/) package, where it does have the option to retry. Ideally the `django_zodb` transaction middleware should do the same.

Comment: @patroqueeet: there is no need to wait a few ms. When there is a conflict, restart the whole transaction there and then with the new data, the other transaction you conflicted with is already done committing.

Comment: perfect. that points me exactly what I was looking for. Will look at pyramid_tm, analyse conflict handling and add it on top of the django_zodb...